# No plugin found for prefix 'docker' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: docker, spring-boot, maven-3, spring-cloud

deploy `Spring Cloud` project with `docker`, some code in the `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!-- tag::plugin[] -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- end::plugin[] -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

when i execute the command: `mvn package docker:build`, it throws the above errors:

```
    Downloaded: http://3.2.4.2:8888/repository/maven-public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (14 KB at 5.7 KB/sec)
    Downloaded: http://3.2.4.2:8888/repository/maven-public/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (21 KB at 7.3 KB/sec)
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Reactor Summary:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] eureka-server ...................................... SUCCESS [ 26.279 s]
    [INFO] service-1 ......................................... SUCCESS [ 14.649 s]
    [INFO] demo1 ........................................... FAILURE [  2.850 s]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 45.535 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-15T14:28:05+08:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 47M/532M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'docker' in the current project 
and in the plugin groups [org.sonatype.plugins, org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/../Repository), nexus (http://3.2.4.2:8888/repository/maven-public/)]
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

add the below code to your maven `conf/setting.xml`：

```
<pluginGroups>  
    <pluginGroup>com.spotify</pluginGroup>  
</pluginGroups>
```

if you want to get more detail, pls refer to https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/issues/322

Answer (score 7):

If you are using dockerfile maven plugin, you need to change docker:build to 
dockerfile:build and  docker:push to dockerfile:push

Answer (score 3):

For me worked in a different way, if you follow the maven plugin pattern `{prefix}-maven-plugin`... which in this case is `dockerfile-maven-plugin`, you should be able to run it with: `mvn package dockerfile:build`.
I'm using Maven: 3, Spring Boot 2 and Docker maven plugin 1.3.4

Comment: what does this mean?  use the maven plugin pattern where?